# How to change default login user for postgresql

Tags: postgresql

When I install postgresql@14 through Homebrew on my Mac, it will create default user called "will" which is my Mac login user.

After that I can use this command to login in postgresql:

```
psql postgreqsql
```

But I want to change the default user to another, instead of add parameter -U, where I can change the default login user.

change the default login user.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the database user or do you want to change the default for the user name that `psql` chooses to connect?